# jquery remove class from image inside li

Tags: jquery, html, class, removeclass

I need to remove the class 'twist' from image inside li that has class 'selected' using jquery

```
<ul class="gal">
 <li>
  <img class="twist" src"..." />
 </li>
 <li class="selected">
  <img class="twist" src"..." />
 </li>
 <li>
  <img class="twist" src"..." />
 </li>
<ul>
```

Somebody please help.

Thanks

Comment: appreciate answers by upvoting ...

Comment: Do you really need jQuery for this? To me it looks like CSS can do the job.

Comment: Your html is invalid - you need a `</ul>`, not a `<ul>` at the end, and `src="..."` instead of `src"..."`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kmhdj/2/

Demo will alert the before and after class attribute.

You can also do `.each` iteration if you are expecting different classes and different outcome.

There is also an API called `.hasClass()` which you can use when you iterate to check if that class exist but all this is extra info.

Hope this helps

**Another demo==> Here is a long cut way using `.each` & `.hasClass` in case you keen:** http://jsfiddle.net/kmhdj/5/

**code**

```
$("ul li.selected img").removeClass("twist");
```

Comment: @Eric hiya, which one bro; please lemme knw; I will correct it thanks man. Oh and by the way it is copy paste from Question :) i.e. html.

Comment: @Eric cool closing ul tag cooleoss http://jsfiddle.net/bncSS/ :) found and fixed. thanks.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized the HTML errors were in the question! Apologies

Answer (score 2):

As simple as that:

```
$("li.selected > img").removeClass("twist");
```

Relatively `<ul>` element it can be done with:

```
$("ul.gal > li.selected > img").removeClass("twist");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove class using **removeClass** method as :

```
$("li.selected > img").removeClass("twist");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.gal img').each(function(){
   if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) 
   $(this).removeClass('twist');
})
```